# Text Styling through class not applying to ProgressBar.js

Tags: javascript, angular, progress-bar

I was trying to create a Promodo Timer app on Ionic 5 using Angular. I am using ProgressBar.js for a progress bar around the timer. According to the progressbar.js docs, they have specified how to set text element styling as follows -

```
/ Text options. Text element is a <p> element appended to container
    // You can add CSS rules for the text element with the className
    // NOTE: When text is set, 'position: relative' will be set to the
    // container for centering. You can also prevent all default inline
    // styles with 'text.style: null'
    // Default: null
    text: {
        // Initial value for text.
        // Default: null
        value: 'Text',

        // Class name for text element.
        // Default: 'progressbar-text'
        className: 'progressbar__label',

        // Inline CSS styles for the text element.
        // If you want to modify all CSS your self, set null to disable
        // all default styles.
        // If the style option contains values, container is automatically
        // set to position: relative. You can disable behavior this with
        // autoStyleContainer: false
        // If you specify anything in this object, none of the default styles
        // apply
        // Default: object speficied below
        style: {
            // Text color.
            // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
            color: '#f00',
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '50%',
            top: '50%',
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
            // You can specify styles which will be browser prefixed
            transform: {
                prefix: true,
                value: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
            }
        },

        // Only effective if the text.style is not null
        // By default position: relative is applied to container if text
        // is set. Setting this to false disables that feature.
        autoStyleContainer: true,

        // Only effective if the shape is SemiCircle.
        // If true, baseline for text is aligned with bottom of
        // the SVG canvas. If false, bottom line of SVG canvas
        // is in the center of text.
        // Default: true
        alignToBottom: true
    },
```

I am able to apply styling through the text object as above, but I was trying to add styling through my scss file using default className - *progressbar-text*. This didn't work. I also tried custom className but this didn't work as well.

My code below -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var ProgressBar: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initBar();
  }

  initBar() {
    let progressBar = new ProgressBar.Circle('.timer', {
      strokeWidth: 2,
      text: {
        value: '25:00',
        style: null,
        className: 'progressbar__label'
      },
      color: '#f4f4f4',
      trailWidth: 0.5,
      trailColor: '#010770'
    })
  }

}
```

My scss -

```
.progressbar__label{
  // Text color.
  // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
  color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  // You can specify styles which will be browser prefixed
  transform: {
    prefix: true;
    value: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Computed Element-

```
<div class="progressbar__label">25:00</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Read ProgressBar.js [docs](https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/).

Comment: You've added the progressbar__label class in the global scss? If not, try that. Also, try using !important just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I am noticing that the class is set on the component, but it's not receiving any stylings from it. I've tried using `!important` on everything but that doesn't work either.

As a workaround, for now, I'm setting `style` instead of `className`

```
text: {
  style: {
    ...all the styling in your class
  }
}
```

I know it's not ideal, and it'd be nice to be able to put the styling into the scss file, but that'll have to do, for now, I guess.